# If else in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Spark Streaming application which is reading data from a SINGLE TOPIC in Kafka, processing it, and inserting it into 2 different keyspaces in Cassandra, based on the content of the element. Some data might go to keyspace A, some other to keyspace B.

I do it currently using filter operation:

```
Functions.insertToCassandra(rdd.filter(element => element.tenant=="A"), keyspace = A, table = "tableName")
Functions.insertToCassandra(rdd.filter(element => element.tenant=="B"), keyspace = B, table = "tableName")
```

So filter is applied on every rdd, those elements that have tenant field A go to keyspace A, and those with tenant field B go to keyspace B.

Is there any more efficient way to do this, instead of applying filter operation 2 times (especially because there might be more than 2 keyspaces later)? Would caching rdd before filter operations increase the performance?

I repeat, I have DStream coming from Kafka, I process it, and then in "foreachRDD" operation I have code snippet from above, which is inserting data to Cassandra.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do

```
Functions.insertToCassandra(rdd.filter(element => element.tenant=="A"), keyspace = A, "tableName")
Functions.insertToCassandra(rdd.filter(element=> element.tenant=="B"), keyspace = B, "tableName")
```

Make sure to do rdd.cache()

When you are doing like above, your spark is trying to read rdd data twice.
Spark never retains any rdd in memory unless you cache or broadcast it.

Another way could be to read all the data at once, cache it, if data set is not enormous. Then use groupByKey, where key will be your keyspace(element) in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Should I add "rdd.unpersist(true)" after filter transfirmations, to release it from memory?

Comment: You can, but if you have this piece of code inside a method. Then once you go outside of that method, it will automatically remove it from memory.

Comment: Also unpersist, if i remember right, keeps result in driver memory and removes it from workers memory. destroy on the other hand, removes it from everywhere.

Comment: Actually I realized that much better is the option with group by key. But what that operation gives me is a (key, Iterable[T]). 

How to insert this iterable collection to cassandra, when cassandra requires RDD[T], and there is no way to move Iterable[T] to RDD[T]?

Thank you very much

Comment: Well you can always use sc.parallelize(YourIterable.toList), but be very careful, your iterable will go through driver and hence easily reach spark.driver.maxResultSize or driver memory.